# including class-less header file in another c++ file

Tags: c++

I have a header file as follows :

```
int64_t *id;
int *sz;

void setupUnionFind(int numNodes)
{
  id = (int64_t *)malloc(numNodes*sizeof(int64_t));
  sz = (int *)malloc(numNodes*sizeof(int));
  for (int64_t i = 0; i < numNodes; i++)
  {
    id[i] = i;
    sz[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

I am including this in another c++ file as follows :

```
#include "headerGile.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"  

class UnionFindMethodsTest : public testing::Test {
  protected:

  //constructor
  UnionFindMethodsTest(){ 
  int numNodes = 10;
  setupUnionFind(numNodes); 

  }

  //destructor
  virtual ~UnionFindMethodsTest(){

  }

};
other functions below this ......
```

When I compile this file, it says that id, sz of the header file was not declared in this scope. I mean it complains the same thing for every variable in the header file. 
I am not able to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: If what you say is true, you don't need any of the code in your C++ file to produce the problem. Just `#include "headerGile.h"` will do it. But this code won't produce the problem you describe; there's something else going on that you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution. I was not including the required header files :

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

I included this both file in header file and this error is gone.